# How to get the sum of data from different dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get 3 data

1. The sum of data between n dates / days
   like, I need to get the sum of 01-12 to 05-12 and this / days = 5
2. The result of 1 but this is for validation
3. The difference between #1 and #2

How to get the sum of data from different dates also I need this 3 points for every segment I have like

| segment | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TTT | 456465 | 456465 | 0 |
| CCC | 478888 | 478886 | 2 |

```sql
select segment,
       (SELECT var1 AS 1.-
               + ( SELECT var1 AS 1.-
                   from table 
                   where data = 20221207
                   group by segement
                 )
        from   table
        where  data = 20221206
        group by segement) AS 1.-,
        sum(IMP_SDO_MED_CONT_ML) AS 2.-,
        (1.- - 2.-) AS difference,
from    table
WHERE   DATA = 20221207
group by segment;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't quite understand what you want. Could you provide **sample data** that illustrates the problem, describe **rules** we should apply to sample data and - finally - **result** based on sample data and rules?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to sum the data using conditional aggregation and then can find #3 using subtraction:

```sql
SELECT segment,
       SUM(CASE WHEN data BETWEEN 20221201 AND 20221212 THEN var1 END) AS "1",
       SUM(IMP_SDO_MED_CONT_ML) AS "2",
       SUM(CASE WHEN data BETWEEN 20221201 AND 20221212 THEN var1 END)
       - SUM(IMP_SDO_MED_CONT_ML) AS "3"
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY segment
```

However, without sample input data it is difficult to check what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

It's realy hard to tell what the question is without the data. Maybe it is about  calculating the difference of sums of two columns in some period per segments. If that is the case then the query would be:

```sql
Select 
    SEGMENT,
    Sum(var_1) "FLD_1",
    Sum(IMP_SDO_MED_CONT_ML) "FLD_2",
    Sum(var_1) - Sum(IMP_SDO_MED_CONT_ML) "DIFF"
From    a_tbl
Where   DATE_NUMBER Between 20221201 And 20221203
Group By SEGMENT
Order By SEGMENT
```

... and if we invent some sample data like below

```sql
WITH
    a_tbl AS
        (
            Select 'AAA' "SEGMENT", 1234 "VAR_1", 1233 "IMP_SDO_MED_CONT_ML", 20221201 "DATE_NUMBER" From Dual Union All
            Select 'AAA' "SEGMENT", 5678 "VAR_1", 5677 "IMP_SDO_MED_CONT_ML", 20221202 "DATE_NUMBER" From Dual Union All
            Select 'AAA' "SEGMENT", 9101 "VAR_1", 9103 "IMP_SDO_MED_CONT_ML", 20221203 "DATE_NUMBER" From Dual Union All
            Select 'BBB' "SEGMENT", 8765 "VAR_1", 8766 "IMP_SDO_MED_CONT_ML", 20221201 "DATE_NUMBER" From Dual Union All
            Select 'BBB' "SEGMENT", 6666 "VAR_1", 6665 "IMP_SDO_MED_CONT_ML", 20221202 "DATE_NUMBER" From Dual Union All
            Select 'BBB' "SEGMENT", 4423 "VAR_1", 4420 "IMP_SDO_MED_CONT_ML", 20221203 "DATE_NUMBER" From Dual Union All
            Select 'CCC' "SEGMENT", 1234 "VAR_1", 1233 "IMP_SDO_MED_CONT_ML", 20221201 "DATE_NUMBER" From Dual Union All
            Select 'CCC' "SEGMENT", 5678 "VAR_1", 5677 "IMP_SDO_MED_CONT_ML", 20221203 "DATE_NUMBER" From Dual Union All
            Select 'DDD' "SEGMENT", 1234 "VAR_1", 1233 "IMP_SDO_MED_CONT_ML", 20221201 "DATE_NUMBER" From Dual Union All
            Select 'EEE' "SEGMENT", 5678 "VAR_1", 5678 "IMP_SDO_MED_CONT_ML", 20221203 "DATE_NUMBER" From Dual 
        )
```

... then the result would be

| SEGMENT | FLD_1 | FLD_2 | DIFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 16013 | 16013 | 0 |
| BBB | 19854 | 19851 | 3 |
| CCC | 6912 | 6910 | 2 |
| DDD | 1234 | 1233 | 1 |
| EEE | 5678 | 5678 | 0 |

**OR maybe** it is the difference between sum of the period for one column and sum of the last day of period for the other column. In that case query could be:

```sql
Select 
    SEGMENT,
  Sum(var_1) "FLD_1",
  Sum(CASE WHEN DATE_NUMBER = 20221203 THEN IMP_SDO_MED_CONT_ML ELSE 0 END) "FLD_2",
  Sum(var_1) - Sum(CASE WHEN DATE_NUMBER = 20221203 THEN IMP_SDO_MED_CONT_ML ELSE 0 END) "DIFF"
From    a_tbl
Where   DATE_NUMBER Between 20221201 And 20221203
Group By SEGMENT
Order By SEGMENT
```

... resulting (with same invented data) as

| SEGMENT | FLD_1 | FLD_2 | DIFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 16013 | 9103 | 6910 |
| BBB | 19854 | 4420 | 15434 |
| CCC | 6912 | 5677 | 1235 |
| DDD | 1234 | 0 | 1234 |
| EEE | 5678 | 5678 | 0 |